# Can I trigger a callback if an attribute is set on a model - i.e. not nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want do an `after_save`, only if `self.firm` is not nil.

I tried this:

```
after_save :set_firm_size, :if => self.firm
```

But that threw an error.

How do I get this to work? Or can it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html):

```
after_save :set_firm_size, :if => Proc.new { |a| a.firm.present? }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a Proc, like shioyama said, or you can create a method and then send that method name as a symbol.  For example:

```
after_save :set_firm_size, :if => :firm_present?

def firm_present?
  self.firm.present?
end
```